# Article selection for the first sentence in the description of a class in the software documentation

Tags: articles

I am in the process of writing a documentation for a software project. I would like to understand what would be the best article to use at the beginning of the first sentence in the description of a class (or another software element).

For example, consider the following documentation sections:

> **class Algorithm**
>
> **The/A** base class for the definition of the classes that represent algorithms in the ssa library. An algorithm is a class that is designed for conversion of the data from one type to another, as opposed to the data storage. ...

...

> **class Filter**
>
> **The/An** abstract base class template that provides an interface for the definition of classes that are meant to represent filters in the dataflow network. ...

What would be the best article to use in each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A case can be made for the use of either.

The ambiguity hinges around whether the article is being applied to the shorter noun phrase ("base class" or "abstract base class template"), in which case using "a/an" would be correct, since there are many base classes and many class templates in most programming languages, or to the longer, "full" one ("base class for..." or "abstract base class template that..."), in which case there is likely only a single class/template which matches the full description, and you would therefore use "the".

Personally, I would go with "the", but that is purely a matter of personal taste and, as far as I'm aware, either would be correct.